# SQL (Azure) using a table var inside a CTE

Tags: sql-server, azure, stored-procedures, while-loop, common-table-expression

My Stored Procedure creates a Common Table Expression to find the "Last Trade"/ "Best Bid" for each listed StockName (the code is lengthy but uses:

```
row_number () OVER ( partition BY StockName ORDER BY Date/Price)
```

and a WHERE Country = 'USA'          )

Whilst that works fine I now want to add the ability to input the results from a separate query (a result set of countries: 'USA', 'CAN', 'MEX') and loop through the SP shown above.

However, I am lost on how and where to do the data passing and/or looping.

Should I have two SP's and pass the values between them???  Or create a loop inside one SP?

Answer (score 1):

You could use SQL CURSOR to loop the query result and invoke the Stored Procedure which you mentioned. Here is a sample of using CURSOR.

```
declare cur_countr cursor for 
    select 'USA' as Country union 
    select 'CAN' as Country union 
    select 'MEX' as Country  

declare @country nvarchar(50)
open cur_countr

fetch next from cur_countr into @country
    while(@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
      begin
         print @country
         -- You will get country here and invoke the Stored Procedure you defined
         fetch next from cur_countr into @country
      end

close cur_countr
deallocate cur_countr
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I have yet to try your suggestion (and fwiw the number of countries in the cursor will vary as the result of a separate query) but I have read previously that cursors should be avoided (like the plague).  

I take it that is not (always) so?

Comment: We can also define a cursor from a query like following. declare cur_countr cursor for select Country from table_countries